# How to use the array intersect method to match two values within 2 sets of arrays

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have this query:

```
$subcommon= MyModel::selectRaw('subjectlist_id, count(subjectlist_id) AS aggregate')
 ->whereIn('user_id', [Auth::id(), $user->id])
->groupBy('subjectlist_id')  
->having('aggregate','>',1)
->get();
```

which gives this query result:

```
{"subjectlist_id":1,"aggregate":2} {"subjectlist_id":3,"aggregate":2}
```

I also have this query:

```
$values = Mysecondmodel::where('user_id', Auth::id())
                         ->first();
```

which gives this result:

```
{"id":1,"subjectlist_id":1, "article_id":4}
```

Because im finding it way too difficult to join these two models i've decided to output them as arrays so I would like at least 1 matching value for `subjectlist_id` as a condition for it to execute the query I've displayed at the bottom. I'm assuming it's the `arrayintersect` method however im unsure how to use it.

```
$values = Mysecondmodel::where('user_id', Auth::id())
                           ->first();
```

I have this so far:

```
 $subcommonarray = (array) $subcommon;

$valuesarray = (array) $values;

$a = $subcommonarray;
$b = $valuesarray;
$c = array_intersect_key($a, $b);

if (count($c) > 0) {


   $newquery = Mysecondmodel::where(user_id, Auth::id())
 ->first(); 

}
```

But this I think is comparing the keys and not the values. How do I match the values and and the key together?

Answer (score 2):

Well if `$values` and `$subcommon` are both valid arrays, you could compare them using the `array_intersect` function like that:

```
$subjectlist_id = array_intersect($values, $subcommon);
```

This would go and search for similarities in **values**, and will construct another array in the `$subjectlist_id` variable of all the matching values between both arrays.

A good example from the [php documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php):

```
$array1 = array(2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12);
$array2 = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);

$array3 = array_intersect($array1, $array2);
var_dump($array3);
```

This would have such an array:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=> int(2)
  [1]=> int(4)
  [2]=> int(6)
}
```

Comment: Thanks but the `array_intersect` method gives me an error saying Array to string conversion. I've now edited my question to give a partial solution at the bottom

Comment: To match the values simply use the `array_intersect` function. It gives you this error cause maybe you are trying to echo or print the array when you actually need to dump it. What code actually causes the Array to string conversion error?

Comment: Sorry I meant the key and value together my mistake. So for the example above I want to match `subjectlist_id:1` coming from the first query and `subjectlist_id:1` coming from my second query. Ultimately i want to echo `$newquery` and not the array but i get the error

Comment: Oh, then you can use the `array_intersect_assoc()` to match key-value in both arrays. :) Mind that you cannot echo `$newquery` cause it's also an array (coming from DB) so you'll have to either `var_dump` or `print_r` it to see the results.

Comment: I get the same error `Array to string conversion` @Shay but when i do `array_intersect_key` I dont get an error but it's matching the just the key

Comment: How do I echo $newquery??? strange how you can echo it without trying to do what im trying to do

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on in your code, but I do know that you get Array to string conversion when you try to echo or print an array. Perhaps it didn't gave you the error because it was only one key so it had no problem echoing it, otherwise use var_dump or print_r!

Comment: Just use `var_dump($newquery)`, this should eliminate the error. Act as if $newquery is an array.

Comment: im using laravel so i need to pass the `$newquery` to my view.

Comment: That's a whole different topic, google Laravel 5 fundamentals there are some pretty good video tutorials on how to pass arrays into views.

Comment: Its quite simple to pass arrays to views. but in this instance it's obviously not.

Comment: @MarkusSmith The answer is correct, why don't you accept it? You accepted the same answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30563761/171318