# How to check for matching key value pairs

Tags: php, arrays, operators

I have sets of arrays with key value pairs:

```
$array1 = array('blue'  => 1, 'red'  => 2, 'green'  => 3, 'purple' => 4);
$array2 = array('green' => 5, 'blue' => 1, 'yellow' => 7, 'cyan'   => 8);
```

How do I check that both arrays contain a match **key and value together**? I want to place a condition so if `$array1` and `$array2` have a matching pair `blue=>1` then I would like to do something?

Comment: Thanks everyone. Im trying to echo out a query using Laravel. but im getting errors. am i better off posting another question?

Comment: No, you should edit your question and add the relevant code which you have tried and describe the problem you are experiencing with it.

Comment: thanks hek2mgl but it's too long and its more laravel to be honest

Comment: Then you need to break it down into an understandable problem which is not related to laravel. This question is simply bad quality. Please read (and understand) the question faq before you go on posting questions!

Comment: This question has helped believe me. I actually posted the question previously but unfortunately i didnt get a suitable answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30561481/how-to-use-the-array-intersect-method-to-match-two-values-within-2-sets-of-array

Comment: You got the same answer there, have not up-voted nor accepted it and opened a new (obviously duplicate) question. And as a result you got more reps than all the quys who tried to help. Something is going wrong here! Isn't it? While you might not having something bad in mind when doing this, it is still not welcome behaviour on this site.

Comment: haha! hek2mgl please! I dont care about reps I care about my problem. I did not know that array_intersect_assoc matched key value pairs. If you read the comments at the bottom of the question you'll see that IT DID NOT solve my problem.

Comment: It wasn't saying that you had that in mind and I don't believe so but it is still the result. The answer suggests to use `array_intersect_assoc()` - which is correct. You got the same answer here, again.

Comment: The `array_intersect_assoc()` is not solving my problem.

Comment: Why did you accepted it? Because of `count()`??

Comment: because it's the correct answer to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [array_intersect_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-assoc.php):

```
php > var_dump(count(array_intersect_assoc($array1,$array2)) > 0);
bool(true)

php > $array1 = array('blue'  => 1, 'red'  => 2, 'green'  => 3, 'purple' => 4);
php > $array2 = array('green' => 5, 'blue' => 2, 'yellow' => 7, 'cyan'   => 8);
php > var_dump(count(array_intersect_assoc($array1,$array2)) > 0);
bool(false)
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop through `$array1` and check if the value is the same for `$array2`:

```
foreach($array1 as $i=>$val){
    if($array2[$i]==$val)
        //do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach( $array as $key => $value ){
  if (array_key_exists($key, $array1)) {
    echo $array[$key] == $array1[$key];
  }
}
```

I think you have to check key exists if I recall correctly as php errors when trying to access a non existent key in a hash.